# NetBeans + PHPUnit no tests executed

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I have a NetBeans project with PHPUnit tests that I am using for learning.
I created it on my desktop PC using NetBeans 8.0.2 it worked fine, but when I imported the project on my notebook PHPUnit don't execute any tests.

This is the output window:

```
"C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\bin\phpunit.bat" "--colors" "--log-junit" "C:\Users\MARCOA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--configuration" "C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests\phpunit.xml" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests"

Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143

Call Stack:
    0.0016     130056   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0385     398928   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
    0.0386     402664   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
    0.1218     887816   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
    0.1910    1624632   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1910    1624648   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1911    1625712   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
    0.1954    1626688   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
    0.2026    1627056   9. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
    0.2061    1627360  10. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
    0.2229    1628168  11. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143


Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143

Call Stack:
    0.0016     130056   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0385     398928   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
    0.0386     402664   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
    0.1218     887816   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
    0.1910    1624632   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1910    1624648   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1911    1625712   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
    0.1954    1626688   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
    0.2026    1627056   9. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
    0.2061    1627360  10. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
    0.2343    1628632  11. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143


Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143

Call Stack:
    0.0016     130056   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0385     398928   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
    0.0386     402664   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
    0.1218     887816   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
    0.1910    1624632   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1910    1624648   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1911    1625712   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
    0.1954    1626688   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
    0.2026    1627056   9. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
    0.2385    1627464  10. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143

PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
PHP   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
PHP   9. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP  10. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP  11. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
PHP   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
PHP   9. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP  10. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP  11. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
PHP   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
PHP   9. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP  10. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP Warni
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143

Call Stack:
    0.0016     130056   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0385     398928   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
    0.0386     402664   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
    0.1218     887816   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
    0.1910    1624632   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1910    1624648   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1911    1625712   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
    0.1954    1626688   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
    0.3064    1627160   9. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143


Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 115

Call Stack:
    0.0016     130056   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0385     398928   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
    0.0386     402664   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
    0.1218     887816   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
    0.1910    1624632   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1910    1624648   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1911    1625712   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
    0.3851    1626672   8. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 84

Call Stack:
    0.0016     130056   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0385     398928   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
    0.0386     402664   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
    0.1218     887816   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
    0.1910    1624632   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
    0.1910    1624648   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89

PHPUnit 4.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests\phpunit.xml



Time: 684 ms, Memory: 2.25Mb

No tests executed!

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
ng:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 143
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
PHP   8. NetBeansSuite::rglob() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
PHP   9. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:143
PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 115
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   7. NetBeansSuite::toRun() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:84
PHP   8. array_merge() C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php:115
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 84
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:104
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:126
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
PHP   6. NetBeansSuite::suite() C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:89
Concluído.
```

I am using Composer.
I already installed the dependencies, pointed the phpunit executable on the bin folder in NetBeans configuration, and done all the same configuration from the project on my desktop that was working fine, but I still get this error.

EDIT:

The files in C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests are

```
C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests\Marco\Test\Manager\InvoiceManagerTest.php
C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests\Marco\Test\Manager\PDOMock.php
C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests\Marco\Test\Model\InvoiceTest.php
```

Comment: Could you list files in `C:\WebServer\Apache 2.2\htdocs\DataBaseTests\tests` directory?

Comment: I'm not expert of Apache under Widnows, but could you check if `tests` directory is accessible for Apache? This warning is thrown beacuse `glob()` function returns `false` for your path.

Comment: Yes, It is accessible, anyway my project on Desktop was outside Apache.
The application doesn't have any output, it's only for testcases study.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the shell script version (bin/phpunit.sh) does not work with Netbeans. Choose libexec/phpunit.phar instead.

I encountered 2 problems. The first has the symptom of 'no tests found' and prints a similar error if you try the command:

```
"/usr/local/bin/php" "/usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/4.3.4/bin/phpunit" "--colors" "--log-junit" "/var/folders/vc/r2k02djd5gg664g0v7ggm8l40000gn/T/nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--bootstrap" "/Users/...bootstrap.php.cache" "--configuration" "/Users/.../app/phpunit.xml.dist" "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=/Users/...Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php"
```

This was fixed by using phpunit/4.3.4/libexec/phpunit.phar.

The second problem I encountered, but with a different symptom was in using phpunit 5.0.0. I used the phar version as above but it appears to have a bug https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1887. It returns

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/5.0.0/libexec/phpunit-5.0.0.phar/phar/phpunit-mock-objects/Framework/MockObject/Builder/InvocationMocker.php on line 82
```